# What gate resistor for IGBT irg4pc50s

Tags: h-bridge, igbt

[image: schematic for IGBT gate driver]

I am building a H-Bridge. This is the schematic of my driver board for 1 of the IGBT's. I do not know how to calculate the R1. The Vge is 15v, The Ic is 41A. What would be the best size of resistor to use?
[**IRG4PC50SPBF datasheet**](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irg4pc50spbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356447adc22f0)

Comment: \$R_g\$ sets the speed that the gate capacitance \$Q_g\$ charges and discharges. That is heavily dependent on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's not a schematic, it is only a (bad) picture!

Answer (score 1):

You take parameters from datasheet: output current, output voltage, on/off resitance. Then a simple ohms law R=U/I. The MOSFET is a capacitor like, when discharged it will sink the current limited by gate resistor, when discharged also. So let's make one rude example:
Vcc=15V
HCPL-3120 max peak current = 2.5A
Vout=Vcc-4
R=(15-4)V/2.5A= 4.4ohm.  Take a resistor from 4.7 to 10 ohm.

Answer (score 0):

R1 is non critical apart from being small.

The main function of R1 is to damp possible ringing of the gate when driven.
It also limits gate capacitance peak charge / discharge current and thereby increases IGBT switching times and reduces EMI and switching losses (The latter tends to be contrary to 'common knowledge or practice*.)

A value around 10 Ohms is typical. At Cg ~~= 4 nF the resistor-cG time constant at 10 Ohms is thus around 40 ns  for a rise time of maybe 100 ns. This is liable to be acceptable at switching speeds 100 kHz and maybe more.

---

*-

> Q: Are you saying that increasing an IGBT switching time ALSO decreases its switching losses?

A: Yes. Switching Losses will generally drop as switching speed increases until some "sweet spot" is reached. Above this losses will increase.

Switching losses are incurred by a range of mechanisms. Changes that reduce one loss may increase another. eg if you are charging or discharging a capacitor then halving the time taken will ~= double the current.
Resistive losses are related to power = I^2 x R.
Energy losses to I^2 x R x t.
If you double current and halve time power goes up by a factor of 4 and energy loss by a factor of 2.

If you switch very slowly then the VI losses while the device transitions from off to on will dominate. So, once you get 'fast enough', faster may increase other losses as above.

Comment: Are you saying that increasing an IGBT switching time ALSO decreases its switching losses?

Comment: @Daniel Yes - above some "sweet spot". Losses are incurred by a range of mechanisms. Changes that reduce one loss may increase another. eg if you are charging or discharging a capacitor then halving the time taken will ~= double the current. Resistive losses are related to power = I^2 x R. Energy to I^2 x R x t. If you double current and halve time power goes up by a factor of 4 and energy loss by a factor of 2.  If you switch very slowly then the VI losses while the device transitions from off to on will dominate. So, once you get 'fast enough', faster may increase other losses as above.

Comment: I see. I guess gate charge current isn't considered very often as an \$I^2R\$ process, since it's usually overwhelmed by the loss in the Drain-Source path. Makes sense though!

Comment: @Daniel - that was an off the cuff example but very fast FET switching can have other potential losses associated with it with a bit of head scratching. I know that that is a practical outcome and long long ago I went through this informally with someone with substantial experience - but I'd need to think harder on it that I've done so far. I think there is more to it than just gate charge handling but so far nothing leaps out of distant memory yelling loudly - but it quite possibly will in the next while as I don't think about it :-). Funny how brains work like that.